# Registering to event and create a new method at run time - c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic

How can I register to event and do some actions at runtime?

For example when the user click on a button I want to register to `OnMyEvent` and run `MyFunc` that let's say initialize some `textBox` with the `OnMyEvent` args.

I'm using winforms and .NET 4.

**EDIT**

Maybe I was unclear... I need the ability to register to existing event and add a new method that will run when the event will fire. All at runtime.

**EDIT2**
i'll try to give an example...
lets say that i have a class named "A" that have many events OnDataRecived OnDataSend etc...
when the application running the user can choose form a combobox event name to register (i got the events list via reflection because they not constracts, they are generated from xml file) and which data to update when the choosed event is fired.

so for the example the user choose to register to the OnDataReceived and he choose to update property named DataStream. some code...

in run time upon user choosing:

```
A.OnDataReceived += (s,e) => MyRunTimeMethod(s,e);

private void MyRunTimeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   DataStream = e.Data.Value
}
```

Comment: Are you using **WPF** or **Winforms**  ?

Comment: Removed dynamic and expression tree tags, not relevant to the question.

Comment: do you have some code you are working with or perhaps a bit more detail.

Comment: @Hammerstein I my opinion, "dynamic" is a very valid keyword here.

Comment: When the user clicks, you want to *call* your method or you want your method to be *registered* as an event handler for some other event?

Comment: @sq33g i want my method to register to exist event but my method is unkwon i need to create the method at run time

Comment: via reflection? Or what else do you have in mind?

Comment: @Hammerstein easy with that trigger finger

Comment: OK, that's clear enough... so what's the question?

Comment: @sq33g i can register to event but how can i create the method to register? "MyRunTimeMethod" in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking how to create a method dynamically at runtime - once you have a reference to that method in a delegate, the question of how to register it to an event is trivial.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx) describes how to do this with MSIL instructions. I doubt that's what you're looking for, but it is an option.

The [C# FAQ blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) has a much more interesting solution using expression trees. I suppose this is the one you were referring to by originally tagging your post with expression-tree.

But I would reconsider using dynamic methods at all. How exactly is the user going to specify what action to perform on the event of his choice? I suspect that the options are limited enough that you can get by with something simpler:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    switch (cmbEvents.SelectedText) {
        case "OnLoad":
            MyControl.OnLoad += (s, e) => SomeSelectedControl.Text = SomeInputControl.Text;
            break;

        //... other cases
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all tnx for the answer. and yes i tagged expression tree and someone edit my post and remove it dont know why... about your answer i need to check if it works in all case. if you have another idea i'll happy to read. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows forms, double clicking a button will bring you to a created on_click event. If you bring up the properties window for the button, theres an events tab. Viewing this will show you which events are available for a control.

I found the best way to understand this, was to look at the code created when adding the events.

**Update:**

As noted, I completely missed the point with my answer. The syntax for subscribing to an event at runtime is the same way as it's done on form Initialize. So I don't get any terminology wrong, here's the link to the msdn documentation;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: He is asking about _runtime_, isn't he?

Comment: Yes, my answer is lacking some detail to explain the way I was thinking.

Comment: @Hammerstein the problem is to create a new method that woll run on the event is fired

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve, does not require you to "Register to event at run time".

If button1 is the button of interest here, simply use.

```
button1.Click += buton1_ClickHandler;
```

button1_ClickHandler should be defined in the same class as your button1. and it should have the signature of the RoutedEventHandler. So, it should be

```
private void button1_ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //method code here
}
```

Comment: so are you saying you dont know until run time what code you eant to execute?